# Get all values from drop-down

Tags: perl, selenium-rc

I'm trying to find a way to get all values and label from drop-down in web page.
With label, I could use:

```
my @labels = $sel->get_select_options('s');
```

Return value is array of label in drop-down.
However, there's no equivalent method for getting all values.

Do you guys know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as in Selenium 1 there is no direct API for this. However you could try this.
Consider a `<select>` like below.
`<select name="mydropdown" id="optionset">` 
    `<option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>`
    `<option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>`
    `<option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>`
`</select>`

Below is the snippet in Java to retrieve values. You can get the logic from this snippet and implement it in Perl.

```
int no_of_options = selenium.getSelectOptions("//select[@id='optionset']").length
String option_values[] = new String[no_of_options];
for (int i=0;i<no_of_options;i++){
   String value = selenium.getAttribute("//select[@id='optionset']/option["+i+"]/@value");
   option_values[i] = value;
}
```

Hope this helps.